# Not empty list is out of index on list[0]

Tags: python, arraylist, indexing

I'm doing this problem on Leetcode: https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/description/

I came up with this solution:

```py
class Solution(object):

    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1, list2):
        x = list1
        y = list2
        listx = []
        listy = []    
        
        while x != None and y != None:
            if x != None:
                listx.append(x.val)
                x = x.next
            if y != None:
                listy.append(y.val) 
                y = y.next
        listz = []
        listz.extend(listx)
        listz.extend(listy)
        listz.sort()
        resultlist = []
        for i in range(len(listz)):
            resultlist.append(ListNode(listz[i]))
        for x in reversed(range(len(resultlist)-1)):
            resultlist[x].next = resultlist[x+1]
        result = resultlist[0] 
        return result
```

Explanation of the code:

1. from the input(ListNode) create two lists
2. merge the lists into one list and sort it
3. create a list of ListNodes(resultlist) "create nodes"
4. create the return ListNode splicing all the nodes from result nodes

This code should work but when I try to run it, it gives me this error:

```py
IndexError: list index out of range result = resultlist[0]"
```

even though the list isn't empty and it contains an element on the index 0.

How can I solve this?

Comment: How do you know it is not empy? What length does it have?

Comment: *"even though the list isnt empty and it contains an element on the index 0"* - no, **the runtime is never wrong**, *your* assumption is wrong, the list definitely has no item at index 0 or the error would not have been thrown. If either of the two input lists is `None` your `listtz` is empty, therefore `resultlist` is empty.

Comment: Also, converting linked list to Python lists back and forth is most likely not within the spirit of the problem. It's incredibly inefficient.

Comment: When i return the list, it doesnt return "[]" it returns:
TypeError: [ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}}}, ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}}, ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}, ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}, ListNode{val: 4, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}, etc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If both list1 and list2 are empty then your resultlist will be empty too (there will be no element at index 0) so check at the start of your method if both lists are empty if yes then return list1 or list2

`if not (list1 and list2): return list1`
and I think your result will some fail test cases.
Please check for edge cases and you can make this code more simple if you use link list and do not use python list

All the best!!!

Comment: Thanks!! I will try to solve it with link lists.

Answer (score 1):

This exercise is all about how you navigate a singly linked list. Building lists and reconstructing the linked list is not a great idea.

The problem in the code shown in the question comes about due to lack of checking against edge cases.

This will perform better and will be more robust:

```
class Solution():
    def mergeTwoLists(self, list1, list2):
        cln = ListNode()
        dln = cln
        while list1 and list2:
            if list1.val < list2.val:
                cln.next = list1
                list1, cln = list1.next, list1
            else:
                cln.next = list2
                list2, cln = list2.next, list2
                
        if list1 or list2:
            cln.next = list1 if list1 else list2
            
        return dln.next
```